# Python pandas DataFrame selection rows and columns based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following:

```
  cl1 cl2 cl3 .... cln
0  aaa bbb ccc .... nnn
1  bbb aaa ccc .... nnn
2  xxx xxx xxx .... xxx
```

Need to select rows, which columns' value(any of them).lower() == 'aaa'
So it is 0 and 1 rows and output shall be:

```
   cl1 cl2 cl3 .... cln
0  aaa bbb ccc .... nnn
1  bbb aaa ccc .... nnn
```

I tried many ways, but all of them requires columns names to be specified, but in my case I have no idea about columns names.

So basically something similar would work if I know column names:

```
df.loc[~df['something1'].str.lower().str.strip().isin(['something2'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can use:

```
df[df.eq('aaa').any(axis=1)]

   cl1  cl2  cl3  cln
0  aaa  bbb  ccc  nnn
1  bbb  aaa  ccc  nnn
```

If `lower()` has to be taken to consideration:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).eq('aaa').any(1)] #thanks Chris
```

Or:

```
df[df.applymap(str.lower).eq('aaa').any(axis=1)]
```

The second one is faster and the firstone can handle NaNs.

Comment: don't forget to handle case issues as the OP suggested `str.lower()`: something like `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).eq('aaa').any(1)]`

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, your solution is part of it. So basically I need the following:
if df.columns.str.lower().str.strip() == 'note' and df[column_name] == 'basename' then I need those rows.

So I need to check not only the values, but also the column names (but not just '==' , + also lower().strip() applied to them)

I think I found the solution by drop_duplicate by selecting only the rows which I need and the value. Trying now.

Comment: Generally my problem is as follows.

I have df (one of rows contains 'basename' value which column_name.lower().strip() == 'note'  (can be 'Note', 'note', '    note', etc.)

and then I keep appending new rows, if somehow new row contains 'basename' value for which the column name again column_name.lower().strip() == 'note', then all previous rows with that value and with that column_name shall be removed except last one.  Python pure code will be

Comment: ** # Python is: ** 
 for column_name in df.columns:
     if column_name.lower().strip() == 'none':
         if df[column_name].str.lower().str.strip().isin(['basebane'])
             # remove this row from df
             df = df.loc[~df[column_name].str.lower().str.strip().isin(['basename'])]

**  # I need all of this written normally by dataframe syntax in one row **